# How to install and configure wso2 stratos 1.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

Is there an installation and configuration guide for Stratos 1.6?

Answer (score 2):

Stratos 1.6 comes as a downloadable pack (which is called the Stratos Local Setup). You can download it from [here](http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos/). It contains a readme and necessary scripts to get you started. Download it and try.

Comment: I downloaded and installed stratos 1.6 in an openebula 3.8.1 Ubuntu 12.04 VM with 6GB RAM and it works fine, it seems to run better than stratos 1.5.2. One thing that was not obvious is that the stratos elb, manager and is  must be started before you can login with the https://stratos-local.wso2.com/carbon url. I had an issue with starting stratos after running initialise.sh to create the databases, running stratos.sh threw errors as some databases, I had to change the grants on nearly all stratos databases before I could bring up stratos and login.

Comment: Yes, Manager and ELB is a must and we have missed it in the Readme. We'll update the Readme soon.

Comment: This user privilege issue is due to the version of MySQL which is being used. Provided script works fine for MySQL 5.2, but it throws the errors you have mentioned for MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Stratos manager is the entry point for Stratos cloud services. So Manager and ELB services should be started in order to access cloud services.

Can you give more details on the database issues you faced. When errors are thrown and what erros are thrown etc.

[meetudara.blogspot.com/2013/02/wso2-stratos-16-how-to-intall-and.html](http://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/wso2-stratos-1-6-how-to-intall-and-configure/)